# Как сослаться на вычисляемый столбец?

Tags: sql

Есть задача:

Какая разница в стоимости между самым дорогим и самым дешевым заказом из США.

решить нужно через онлайн тренажер вот здесь:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

```
SELECT Customers.Country, SUM(Quantity*Price) as Sum, OrderDetails.OrderID
FROM Customers join Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
join OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
join Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID
where Customers.Country IN ('USA')
GROUP BY OrderDetails.OrderID
```

Написал код, который считает стоимость заказов из штатов. Есть ли способ обратиться к вычисляемому столбцу Sum? Потому, что если в SELECT прописывать

`MaX(Sum)-Min(Sum) as diff`

появляется ошибка no such column:

Comment: Алиас выходного поля не может использоваться в выражении другого выходного поля, следует использовать исходное выражение. Но у тебя другая проблема - ты хочешь использовать два уровня группировки (`MAX(SUM(Quantity*Price))`), а это в принципе невозможно. Только CTE/подзапрос.

Comment: Кстати, если нужна только "разница в стоимости между самым дорогим и самым дешевым заказом из США" - за каким хреном в выходном наборе нужны поля Country и OrderId?

Answer (score 0):

Получилось решить через подзапросы:

```
WITH Summa_z AS
    (SELECT  OrderDetails.OrderID, Quantity*Price as Summa FROM Products
        INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID GROUP BY OrderDetails.OrderID ORDER BY Quantity*Price DESC),
     USA AS
    (SELECT  Orders.CustomerID, Country, OrderID  FROM Customers
        INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID WHERE Country IN ('USA'))

SELECT Max(Summa)-Min(Summa) as Result FROM Summa_z join USA ON USA.OrderID = Summa_z.OrderID
```